# Firestore security rule MapDiff methods on nested object

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am curious how [MapDiff methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) work on nested object

for example `addedKeys`, for top level only object

```
{"a":1}.diff({}).addedKeys() == ["a"].toSet()
```

this is how it works

but what about nested object?

```
{"a":{"b":"1"},"c":"2"}.diff({}).addedKeys() == [????].toSet()
```

and is the behaviour same on `affectedKeys`, `changedKeys`, `removedKeys` and `unchangedKeys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I use rules.debug and found the answer

in the log, it prints

```
set_value {
  values {
    string_value: "a"
  }
  values {
    string_value: "c"
  }
}
```

so basically `{"a":{"b":"1"},"c":"2"}.diff({}).addedKeys() == ["a","c"].toSet()`

it ignores nested property